# Call Childbrowser with target="_blank" / Cordova 2.0 / jQuery Mobile 1.2.0

Tags: iphone, jquery-mobile, phonegap-plugins, cordova-2.0.0, childbrowser

I've built a Cordova 2.0 App for iOS with jQuery Mobile 1.2. Framework inside. I've successfully installed the Childbrowser plugin (in [this version](https://github.com/Shereef/ChildBrowserOnCordova200) and  with [this guide](https://github.com/andreassolberg/jso/blob/master/README-Phonegap.md). Thanks for the help from these nice guys at this point,

Now I can call the Childbrowser directly with an onclick event with this javascript in the head:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  app.initialize();
  function launchCB() {
    if(window.plugins.childBrowser != null) {
      window.plugins.childBrowser.onLocationChange = function(loc){};
      window.plugins.childBrowser.onClose = function(){};
      window.plugins.childBrowser.onOpenExternal = function(){};
      window.plugins.childBrowser.showWebPage('http://www.google.de');
    } else {
      alert('not found');
    }
  }
</script>
```

OR directly with for example

```
<a href="#" onclick="window.plugins.childBrowser.showWebPage('http://www.google.de');"> Google</a>
```

Now I want to open all links with the attribute `target="_blank"`. Therefore I've found [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10632203/childbrowser-plugin-in-phonegap-1-7-can-open-only-for-the-first-time) and picked up the solution by Charlie Gorichanaz.

But when I start the application in the iPhone simulator, all I get is the sandclock or rather the spinning wheel of death of jQuery mobile.

I'm happy for every helpful advice, I never coded before this app. Here's my index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <meta name = "format-detection" content = "telephone=no"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width;" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />
    <title>Cordova</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova-2.0.0.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="ChildBrowser.js"></script>
    <gap:plugin name="ChildBrowser" /> <!-- latest release -->
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="EmailComposer.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      app.initialize();
      function launchCB() {
        if(window.plugins.childBrowser != null) {
          window.plugins.childBrowser.onLocationChange = function(loc){};
          window.plugins.childBrowser.onClose = function(){};
          window.plugins.childBrowser.onOpenExternal = function(){};
          window.plugins.childBrowser.showWebPage('http://www.google.de');
        } else {
          alert('not found');
        }
      }
      /*
       var args;
       cordova.exec(null, null, "EmailComposer", "showEmailComposer", [args]);
     */
   </script>
   <!-- jQuery mobile -->
   <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="jqm/jquery.mobile-1.2.0-alpha.1.min.css">
   <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="jqm/Changes.css">
   <script type="text/javascript" src="jqm/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
   <script>
     // for using childbrowser to open pdf on remote sites
     $(document).bind( "mobileinit", function() {
       $.mobile.allowCrossDomainPages = true;
     }
   );
   // the function i want to implement
   $(document).bind("pageinit", function() {
     onDeviceReady();
   });
   function onDeviceReady() {
     var root = this;
     cb = window.plugins.childBrowser;
     if (cb != null) {
       $('a[target="_blank"]').click(function(event) {
         cb.showWebPage($(this).attr('href'));
         event.preventDefault();
         event.stopImmediatePropagation();
         return false;
       });
     }
   }
   // don't know is this thing is right in place...
   document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
 </script>
 <script src="jqm/jquery.mobile-1.2.0-alpha.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <section data-role="page" id="home" data-theme="a" data-position="fixed">
    <div data-role="header"> <!-- header -->
      <h1>Test</h1>
      <div style="position:absolute; top:0px; right:5px;">
        <a href="#about" data-transition="pop">
          <img src="images/schlange-sw.png" alt="Schlange">
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /header -->
    <div data-role="content"> <!-- content -->
      <a id="domainbut" onclick='launchCB()'>Working </a>
      <a href="http://www.google.de/" target="_blank" data-role="button" data-inline="true"> not working </a>
    </div>
    <!-- content -->
    <div data-role="footer" data-theme="a" data-position="fixed"></div>
  </section>
  <section data-role="dialog" id="about" data-close-btn-text="Close This Dialog">
    <div data-role="header">
      <h1>Über</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
      <h1 style="text-align: center;"></h1>
      <div align="center">
    </div>
    <p style="text-align: center;">The owner of this app</p>
    <button onclick="cordova.exec(null, null, 'EmailComposer', 'showEmailComposer', [args]);">Compose Email</button>
    <p>
      <a href="#home" data-role="button" data-rel="back">OK</a>
    </p>
  </div>
</section>
</body>
</html>
```

Thank you in advance.

Regards

Kieke

Comment: Did you get any error on console?

Answer (score 1):

@Kieke, if you decide to do away with ChildBrowser, I found the following worked for me.

NOTE: Assuming you are using PhoneGap 2.x

In your `Cordova.plist` set `OpenAllWhitelistURLsInWebView = YES` and set your `ExternalHosts` list, `*` is fine.  Anything you want the webview not to block (viewed in Safari or in the app) has to be in your `ExternalHosts` list.

In your `MainViewController.m` add the following code to the bottom, you can manually redirect any URL to Safari, see the `if` statement for `www.loadDomainInSafari.com`:

```
- (BOOL) webView:(UIWebView*)theWebView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest*)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
    NSURL *requestURL =[ [ request URL ] retain ];
    NSString *host = [ [ requestURL host] retain ];

    // if YES, directs to WebView
    // otherwise, takes OpenAllWhitelistURLsInWebView setting

    // if www.loadDomainInSafari.com, open in Safari by explictly stating NO.
    // otherwise take OpenAllWhitelistURLsInWebView setting of YES
    if ([host isEqualToString:@"www.loadDomainInSafari.com"]) {
        return ![ [ UIApplication sharedApplication ] openURL: [ requestURL autorelease] ];
    }
    [ requestURL release ];
    return [super webView:theWebView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:request navigationType:navigationType];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `Cordova.plist`, do you have `OpenAllWhitelistURLsInWebView = YES` and are all the domains (eg. www.google.com, localhost) you are connecting to are in your `ExternalHosts` list?

Look in the console of your Xcode debugger as @Littm describes, you will see if your link are being blocked because they aren't in the whitelist.

You can also check your system.log as well, `tail /var/log/system.log` for any errors after you execute.

Comment: Thanks für the advice, but there are no whitelist rejections. I have set an Asterisk in Externalhosts, so that all requests are allowed. I think there is a mistake somewhere in my code, but i dont get any errors in the console. I would be happy, if it would be a rejection, but i will check the log you mentioned.

Comment: @Kieke, check the answer above, it shows you how to manually open a Safari window given an if-condition.  No plug-in required.